# change ip address for 10 computers based on a txt file in powershell or vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a txt file that looks like this

```
PC1 192.168.0.2  
PC2 192.168.0.3  
PC3 192.168.0.4
```

I would like to change computers ip addresses based on that list, so it will fill up the computer name and the ip address and process them all without manually changing the values, and I'm having issues getting this to work "still learning powershell"

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ??? win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"

$wmi.SetGateways("192.168.0.1", 1)
$wmi.EnableStatic("?????", "255.255.255.0")
```

any help on that?

Comment: DHCP reservations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your txt file is just a space-separated list of `[computername] [ip-address]`, you can use the [`Import-Csv` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx):

```
$Computers = Import-Csv -Path C:\file.txt -Delimiter " " -Header Name,IP

foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    # Query $Computer.Name
    # Assign $Computer.IP as the static address
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Mathias' answer is perfectly suited for the question as asked. A much better, more maintainable way to accomplish the goal, however, is to use a DHCP server with reservations.

Comment: +1, could not agree more